# What is the Quantum Mechanical analogue of the Bethe-Salpeter equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, greens-functions, propagator

For studying the bound states of quantum fields theories (e.g. studying excitons or mesons), the [Bethe-Salpeter equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe%E2%80%93Salpeter_equation) is often used as the starting point.

Quoting Wikipedia the Bethe Salpeter equation is given by:
$$\Psi=S_1 S_2 K_{12} \Psi$$

Where $\Psi$ is the wavefunction being solved for, $S$ is the free propagator and $K$ is the interaction kernel.

As far as I can understand the equation comes about by assuming the existence of a pole in the Green function (a bound state) and subsequently expanding "around" this pole to study the bound state.

My question is: **is there a quantum mechanical analogue to this equation?**, because it really seems like there should be. If such an analogue exists, is it ever used and why or why not? Looking at the form of the Bethe-Salpeter equation above, it does not seem like relativity is needed either, so perhaps a QM version is possible, not just a QFT one.